# How many elements in the group $Q_{8}\times S_{_{3}}$ have degree 12?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the group $Q_{8}$ and $S_{3}$. How many elements of the group $Q_{8}\times S_{_{3}}$ have degree 12?

Comment: If an element of $Q_8 \times S_3$ is written $(g,x)$ for $g \in Q_8$ and $x \in S_3$, what are the conditions on the orders of $g$ and $x$ in their respective groups for $(g,x)$ to have order 12?

Comment: @orlandpm Something does not seem to mind

Comment: In the notation I used before, do you know what $(g,x)\cdot (h,y)$ is?

Comment: @orlandpm yes. SO the order of $(g,x)$ become $gcd(o(g),o(x))$

Comment: @orlandpm   I'm confused. Please solve the problem for me.

Comment: shoma ehyanan yeki az azaye entesharat marbot be doktora nistid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(g,x)$ is an element of $Q_8 \times S_3$, its order is the least common multiple of the orders of $g$ in $Q_8$ and $x$ in $S_3$.

The group $Q_8$ has one element of order $2$ and six elements of order $4$.  The group $S_3$ has two elements of order $3$ and three element of order $2$.

I'll leave it to you to count pairs of elements whose orders have $LCM =12$.